# UPDATE with Comboboxes

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a problem with my `UPDATE` function. The programme should ask the user if he wants to overwrite one record which is already in the table. So I thought the following code would do it:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim Box As String
If DCount("*", "tblEvents", "Event = '" & Me!EventName & "' AND Date1= " & Format(CDate(Me!Date1), "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#")) > 0 Then
    Box = MsgBox("There is already a price for the event on the selected date. Do you want to overwrite the price?", vbYesNo)
    If Box = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        strSQL = "UPDATE tblEvents SET Price = '" & Me!Price & "' WHERE Event = '" & Me!EventName & "' AND Date1 = " & Format(CDate(Me!Date1), "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#)")
    End If
Else [Save new record]
End If
```

The code runs but it doesn't overwrite the price...

Comment: Get the value of these Me!Price,Me!Event and Format(CDate(Me!Date1), "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#)" then put the values in access query editor just to check if it's updating or not

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
Dim strSQL As String
    Dim Box As String
    'Declare variables for your controls here so that you can check what value it returns in debug mode
    Dim EventName As String = Me!EventName
    Dim Price As String = Me!Price
    Dim Date1 As String = Format(CDate(Me!Date1), "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#")

    If DCount("*", "tblEvents", "Event = '" & EventName & "' AND Date1= " & Date1) > 0 Then
        Box = MsgBox("There is already a price for the event on the selected date. Do you want to overwrite the price?", vbYesNo)
        If Box = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        Else
            strSQL = "UPDATE tblEvents SET Price = '" & Price & "' WHERE Event = '" & EventName & "' AND Date1 = " & Date1
            'Your SQL execute code here 

        End If
    Else
        'Your SQL execute code here for Save
    End If

End Sub
```

Now that you get the values of Price,EventName and Date1, try to execute your update query in access editor just to test if the values you get from you code is really working.

```
UPDATE tblEvents SET Price = '123' WHERE Event = 'party' AND Date1 ='2016/09/23'
```